# how to get all the posts that are posted on WordPress website using php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making my own piece of app in PHP and I want to display all the posts that I have posted on my WordPress website **(both are on the same server)**. I know that WordPress stores data in a database but I am having trouble in finding all the parts of the posts.

So my question is how can one access each and every post and article that are published on my WordPress website.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Probably look here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description.

Comment: @user3783243 nothing found there

Comment: @PeterM i have tried to find the post data in wp_post, wp_terms, wp_terms_relation, wp_terms_taxonomy... but i can only find the heading and slug of the posts in wp_terms

Comment: The DB structure isn't the same? From that diagram your data should be in `wp_posts`. `wp_terms` is two levels from the posts table. Please add how you are retrieving the title and what you have tried with the `posts` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WordPress just use the native WordPress functions, namely the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( ['posts_per_page' => -1]);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // All Post Data Available Now
        // Do what you want with it
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Inside the `while` loop you have access to all the relevant post information using standard WP functions like [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title), and even [`get_post_custom()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) if you have custom fields.

Comment: thanks it worked for me, i was trying to get it from plain php without using wp function but now i will use this instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to access all WordPress functions you need to add this to your php file.

```
<?PHP

    // require wp-load.php to use built-in WordPress functions
    require_once("../wp-load.php");

?>
```

Now all you need is, use your mind and WordPress skills to get the posts using basic WP functions.